# Spring RestController custom view resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've recently started implementing an application using spring, and particularly making some use of the `@RestController` annotations. I've defined a custom view resolver before for normal controllers, but I'm wondering how I could do something similar for the rest controller. I'm just trying to capture the JSON before it gets returned so I can pretty print it.

I guess since it's not really routing to a "view" a view resolver is probably the wrong approach. What should I be using? Can I use a `HandlerInterceptor` perhaps? How would I target only `@RestController` annotated classes?

Comment: Why so complex? When working with JSON generally you use Jackson you can configure this to pretty print the JSON by simply configuring it correctly.

Comment: I'm aware that Jackson supports pretty printing, I just wasn't sure of how to configure the instance that's being used by Spring. I probably should have stated that explicitly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller (most likely) ends up returning an object which gets serialized as JSON by the appropriate [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) -- probably [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html).

As the message converter writes the JSON representation of your returned object directly to the response output stream, you will need to subclass `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and overwrite its `writeInternal` method to get a chance to apply your custom logic around the serialization. Then you'll need to register this custom converter instead of the default one (or at least *before* it).

If your post-processing can be replaced by customized serialization that can be handled by jackson, the best choice would be to set up an `ObjectMapper` appropriately and pass that to the jackson message converter at construction time.

I don't think an interceptor can do much for you, as it only provides you with a `ModelAndView` 
containing the object returned from your controller, not its serialized version.

As an alternative, you can of course use a request filter (outside the whole Spring MVC lifecycle), provide a custom HTTP response wrapper (with some `ByteArrayOutputStream` to accumulate the JSON output) and then post-process that before writing it to the real response output stream.

Comment: Registering my own object mapper sounds like the best solution to me. I will look into how to pass it on to the message converter. Thank you!

Comment: You are aware that the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` has a property `prettyPrint` which defaults to `false`? Just set that to `true` and be done with it. So no overriding or other things to do, just configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HandlerInterceptorAdapter  as described [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter)

As you can see it's possible to configure interception mapping like this

```
<!-- Configuring interceptors based on URI -->
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/home" />
        <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.RequestProcessingTimeInterceptor"></beans:bean>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

Comment: The OP wants to "to capture the JSON before it gets returned so I can pretty print it". How would you do that with an interceptor, which is called either before JSON has been generated (too early) or after it has been sent to the client (too late)?